# Which browsers support -webkit-text-fill-color?

Tags: css, html, browser, cross-browser

I wonder which browsers and versions like Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox,
Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera support `-webkit-text-fill-color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MDN you can see the browser compatibility : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color

As you can see, `-webkit` prefix only applies to webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari).

Other prefixes can target other browsers, like `-o`, `-moz`, `-ms`.

---

Be also aware that it is not a standard property, according to the same page.
It may be why you can't see yet it on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com).

Comment: is there any equivalent of this property that applies the same thing for other browsers that dont support?

Comment: Well, this is another question.  
I would go for a `text-shadow` effect, I guess.